# use of "\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}" creates too much space at right side of each page of paper

Tags: spacing, formatting, positioning, templates

I am facing some issues in formatting of my paper. The template I have downloaded from journal "https://www.springer.com/journal/11277/submission-guidelines" and the option they said to choose for formatting is "\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}". After this, there is too much space at the right side of each page in the output paper, also authors names are not lying in single line.

Comment: presumably the journal knows what size paper it will be printed on and sets the sizes accordingly. the white space you get if you print drafts on A4 is not important.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @David. Sir as I have to submit this draft in this journal, so is it ok to send it while having this spacing issues?

Comment: if you change the layout of a journal supplied class then the most likely result is that the journal will reject the submission.